# Showing that algorithm has STOP property and finding its computational complexity function

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity, correctness-proof

The task is to show that given algorithm has STOP property and to find its computational complexity function.

$\alpha:$ $n \ge 0$

```
void fun(int n) { 
    a=0;b=n+1; 
    while ((a + 1) != b) {
        p = (a + b)/2;
        if (p ∗ p > n) 
            b = p; 
        else a = p; 
    }
}
```

I have already proven its partial correctness as it was also part of the task, however I do have problem with these things that I have mentioned above.

I think it can be easily seen that it is gonna stop as 'a' is getting bigger and bigger, but I don't really know how to notate or show it in more mathematical way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: By "STOP property" you mean the algorithm terminates?

Comment: Also, is `(a + 1)! = b` supposed to be `(a + 1) != b` or do you really mean the factorial $(a + 1)!$ of $a + 1$?

Comment: Yes. It means that the number of steps is finite so it will terminate as you have written.

Comment: It is supposed to be $(a+1)$ != $b$ (is not equal)

Comment: Well, the "more mathematical way" of showing termination usually bases on *loop invariants*. Were those already covered in your course?

Comment: Yes, we have already covered it. I have even used it to prove partial correctness of this algorithm. $\gamma: a < b$ and $a^2 <= n$

Comment: You should be able to prove that, if $b-a > 1$, then after one iteration the difference $b-a$ decreased. This is because one of those endpoints was moved to $p$ which lies in the middle. So, eventually $b-a=1$ (since the difference is always positive, according to your invariant) and the loop stops.

Comment: It seems to me that the condition in the "if" statement is completely irrelevant if you only want to know that the algorithm halts.

Answer (score 1):

You have already proven $a < b$. Let $g$ be the gap between $a$ and $b$, so $b - a$.

1. Show that the algorithm terminates when $g = 1$.
2. Show that when $g > 1$ we have as postcondition that the new $g' \leq \lceil g/2 \rceil$ in the loop body, and thus $g' < g$.
3. Show that it's impossible to skip $g = 1$, and thus the algorithm must terminate.